# REGEXP to grab all text before second underscore, including second underscore

Tags: regex

So I have strings that come across like this:

```
GRF_STHB_010_00  
ABC_AB9_004_01
BGH_NP2_002_03
AG2_BVT_007_010
```

The text before the first underscore can be any combo of Letters or Numbers.

The text before the second underscore can also be any combo of letters or numbers.

I want to be able to grab the whole string before the 2nd underscore, including the second underscore.

I have come up with this for now:

```
^([^\d]*)
```

It works for the first one, and finds:

```
GRF_STHB_
```

But for the other two it stops at a number that it finds:

```
ABC_AB
BGH_NP
AG
```

I need this to work in REGEXP because this is being included in a spreadsheet for grabbing data.

How can I adjust it so that it works with numbers and would have a result of:

```
GRF_STHB_
ABC_AB9_
BGH_NP2_
AG2_BVT_
```

Here is a quick tester for anyone that can help:

[regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B%5E%5Cd%5D%2a%29&input=GRF_STHB_010_00%20%20%0AABC_AB9_004_01%0ABGH_NP2_002_03%0AAG2_BVT_007_010)
Thanks!

Comment: are the underscores always present in your input?

Comment: yes they are always there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this :

```
^[^_]*_[^_]*_
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex for this:

```
^([^_]*_){2}
```

**Online Demo: http://regex101.com/r/cX7hL7**

Comment: While this works in the demo.. it doesn't appear to want to work in my Google Spreadsheet.  Very interesting.

Comment: Hmm Google spreadsheet might be supporting very limited capabilities. You can also try: `^.*_.*_` there

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
^([^_]*_[^_]*)_.*$
```

[Demo](http://regexpal.com/?flags=gm&regex=%5E%28%5B%5E_%5D%2a_%5B%5E_%5D%2a%29_.%2a%24&input=GRF_STHB_010_00%20%20%0AABC_AB9_004_01%0ABGH_NP2_002_03%0AAG2_BVT_007_010)